# Modify my rChart based on a reactive input?

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I am having trouble with some code that I've written.

Here is a sample of the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_P5xxzYr7HOkaZFfFiDhanqDSuSIrd2UkiC-6_G2q0/edit?usp=sharing

**Objective:**
I have a `dataset` that contains a column of `Purchase_Month`, `candy` and `freq` of the number of times that type of candy was purchased in that given month.

I have an `rPlot` which I was to change based on the chosen Candy bar in the `SelectInput`.  And output a line chart based on the number of times that candy was purchased that month.

I have my current code below, but it tells me that `candyCount` is not found.

```
        ## ui.R ##
        library(shinydashboard)
        library(rCharts)

        dashboardPage(
          dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),

          dashboardSidebar(
            width = 150,
            sidebarMenu(
              menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("bar-chart"))
            )

          ),

          dashboardBody(

          sidebarPanel(

              htmlOutput("candy")

            ),
            mainPanel(
              showOutput("plot2", "polycharts")
            ))




            )

    ##server.R##   
        library(rCharts)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(ggvis)

    server <- function(input, output, session) { 

      output$candy <- renderUI({

        available2 <- dataset[(dataset$candy == input$candy), "candy"]

        selectInput(
          inputId = "candy",
          label = "Choose a candy:  ",
          choices = sort(as.character(unique(available2))),
          selected = unique(available2[1])
        )
      })
      observeEvent(input$candy, {
    candyChoice<- toString(input$customer_issue)
    print(candyChoice)
    candyCount<- dataset[dataset$candy == candyChoice, ]
  })
      })

      output$plot2 <- renderChart2({
        p2 <- rPlot(freq~purchase_month, data = candyCount, type = 'line')
        p2$guides(y = list(min = 0, title = ""))
        p2$guides(y = list(title = sprintf("%s Claims",input$candy)))
        p2$addParams(height = 300, dom = 'chart2')
        return(p2)
      })


      }
```

**Updated Data**: Why wouldn't this work?

```
  candyCount<- reactive({
    dataset[dataset$candy == input$candy, ]
    })

  output$plot2 <- renderChart2({
    p2 <- rPlot(freq~purchase, data = candyCount(), type = 'line')
    p2$guides(y = list(min = 0, title = ""))
    p2$guides(y = list(title = ""))
    p2$addParams(height = 300, dom = 'chart2')
    return(p2)
  })
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's hard to help without some toy data.  That said, you write in your preamble that you have a column named `Candy`, but in your code it says `"candy"` (shot in the dark). Remember, R is case sensitive.

Comment: I have provided a sample dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output$candy <- renderUI({

    available2 <- dataset[(dataset$candy == input$candy), "candy"]

    selectInput(
      inputId = "candy",
      label = "Choose a candy:  ",
      choices = sort(as.character(unique(available2))),
      selected = unique(available2[1])
    )
  })
```

In the above you are trying to subset by an input, which is inside your output. The `selectInput` needs to be inside `UI.R`.

A working basic example you may find useful.

```
library(shiny)
df <- read.csv("/path/to/my.csv")

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

       headerPanel('Candy Data'),
       sidebarPanel(
             selectInput('candy', 'Candy', unique(as.character(df[,2])), selected = "Twix")

         ),
       mainPanel(
             plotOutput('plot1')
         )
 ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  selectedData <- reactive({
    df[which(df[,2] == input$candy),3]
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(selectedData())
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the above example the `ui` renders a `selectInput` which has the ID `candy`. The value, i.e the candy selected is now assigned to `input$candy` scope. In `server` we have a `reactive` function watching for any `input` change. When the user selects a new candy this function, `df[which(df[,2] == input$candy),3]` is saying "subset my data frame, df, by the new `input$candy`". This is now assigned to the `selectedData()`. Finally we render then boxplot.

***EDIT***

`server.R`

```
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 500)
df <- read.csv("path/to/my.csv")
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  selectedData <- reactive({
    df[which(df[,2] == input$candy),]
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderChart({
    p <- rPlot(freq~purchase_month, data = selectedData(), type = "line")
    p$addParams(dom = 'plot1')
    return(p)
  })
})
```

`ui.R`

```
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel('Candy Data'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('candy', 'Candy', unique(as.character(df[,2])), selected = "Twix")

  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput('plot1', 'polycharts')
  )
))
```

save files in directory and then `runApp`.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in this line: df[which(df[,2] == input$candy),3]?

Comment: Have expanded my answer a little. Also check out http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I'm receiving the following error: Error in eval(i, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

Comment: Sorry @Nick, I had rearranged your csv and forgot to change the column it was subsetting on. Have fixed that, the example will work now

Comment: Does `selectedData` return `df` when it is called?

Comment: When I try to use this with `rCharts`, it tells me that Object `freq` is not found.

Comment: And why wouldn't my "Update" work that I posted in the original question?

Comment: Im unsure, im playing with it now. Can't say I have overly familiar with `rCharts` package. I get it running but for some reason the plot displays in my RStudio graphic display rather that the app window. Also bare in mind for ease I didnt split the above into a `ui.R` & `server.R` files.

Answer (score 1):

At `available2` you're filtering the data about a selected candy with `dataset$candy == input$candy`. But you use the same `available2` to determine which are the `choices` at `selectInput`. I'm guessing you wanted: `available2 <- dataset[, "candy"]`.

Comment: I'm just using `available2` to help create the subset in my `selectInput`.  I think my main issue is at everything starting with the `observeEvent` function.  When I print `CandyChoice`, the value changes whenever I change the `selectInput`.  I just don't know how to get that value into `CandyCount` and then have it graph the data in `CandyCount`.

Comment: Regarding `available2`, notice you are trying to use an `input` that is supposed to be definied by the same `available2`.  @amwill04 explained this better. Moreover, notice that you want to list all possible candies in `choices` and not just the one selected by the user. Maybe it would be clarifying to print `sort(as.character(unique(available2)))` out.